# min / max functionality in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How would you find using jQuery an element with maximal "page" value which is less than "6" ?

Suppose that "page" has only numerical values, and that the elements are sorted by "page". For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div page="1"></div>
  <div page="2"></div>
  <div page="4"></div>      => answer
  <div page="6"></div>
  <div page="7"></div>
  <div page="9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it have to be done with jQuery?

Comment: there's no built-in jQuery support for doing this, it just makes iterating over the elements and accessing their attributes much easier than pure JS.

Comment: Question: Does always an element exist the value you are looking for (i.e. `6`)? Are the elements always sorted in the DOM tree (i.e. sorted by page value)?

Comment: I can't assume that there is an element with value 6. But, I **can** assume that the elements are sorted by "page" (I edited the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select all the selectors less than 6, and then select the last one.

```
$('#wrapper div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('page') < 6;
}).last().css('color', 'red');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/rFYfM/

Comment: I just finished writing exactly the same code (but without css)

Comment: @Felix Kling Good point. I presumed from the question that they were

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't (originally) specify whether the list is sorted, I'll assume they're not, in which case you must iterate over all of the elements and record the one that matches:

```
var maxEl = null;
var maxNum = 0;

$('#wrapper > div').each(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('page');
    if (num > maxNum && num < 6) {
        maxNum = num;
        maxEl = this;
    }
});

// result is in maxEl
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/WdT2m/ for working demo

Comment: Thanks for your general answer, but Niklas has guessed better my intention via the example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for unsorted list:

```
i = 0;
$('div').filter(function(){
    $thispage = $(this).attr('page')
    if($thispage < 6 && $thispage > i){
        i = $thispage;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).last()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#wrapper > div[page]")
.filter( function() { return parseInt($(this).attr("page")) < 6; } )
.sort( function(a,b) { return parseInt($(a).attr("page")) - parseInt($(b).attr("page")); } )
.last();
```

Broken down:

- Grabs all div's
  immediately within your wrapper that
  have a `page` attribute.
- Filters to include only those elements that are
  less than 6.
- Sorts 
  these elements. (can skip this if you know your div's are sorted).
- Selects the last element found, and thus the element that meets your condition.